# In JavaScript Canvas, How do I keep my drawing inside my canvas after shifting it with a function?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to move my drawing with "up", "down", "left", "right" and "reset". However, I would like to keep it inside of the canvas at all times, so when I click any of the buttons and move the drawing, it would touch the borders but not go outside of the border. Here is what I have so far...

HTML

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas></br>
<button id="up">Up</button><br>
<button id="left">Left</button>     
<button id="right">Right</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button></br>
<button id="down">Down</button>
```

JavaScript

```js
let c, ctx, pos, centerX, centerY, radius, eyeRadius, eyeXOffset, eyeYOffset

window.onload = function() {
  c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  centerX = c.width / 2;
  centerY = c.height / 2;  
  radius = 70;
  eyeRadius = 10;
  eyeXOffset = 25;
  eyeYOffset = 20;  
  reset();
}

function drawFace(){
  //my drawObject() from last assignment - separated into 3 different parts
  // Draw the yellow circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(centerX + pos.left, centerY + pos.top, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawEyes(){
  //my drawObject() from last assignment - separated into 3 different parts
  // Draw the eyes
  let eyeX = centerX + pos.left - eyeXOffset;
  let eyeY = centerY + pos.top - eyeYOffset;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(eyeX, eyeY, eyeRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();  
  ctx.beginPath();
  eyeX = centerX + pos.left + eyeXOffset;
  ctx.arc(eyeX, eyeY, eyeRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawMouth(){
  //my drawObject() from last assignment - separated into 3 different parts
  // Draw the mouth
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(centerX + pos.left, centerY + pos.top, 50, 0, Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  drawFace();
  drawEyes();
  drawMouth();
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}

function reset() {
  pos = {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }
  draw();
}

function up() {
  pos.top -= 20;
  draw();
}

function down() {
  pos.top += 20;
  draw();
}

function left() {
  pos.left -= 20;
  draw();
}

function right() {
  pos.left += 20;
  draw();
}

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = reset;
document.getElementById("up").onclick = up;
document.getElementById("down").onclick = down;
document.getElementById("left").onclick = left;
document.getElementById("right").onclick = right;
```

Comment: you should change the position of  `canvas`.you need to set `position:absolute`

Comment: You will need to check if the drawing is on the edge and stop it. For example `function up() {  
  pos.top -= 20;
  if(pos.top < -centerY + radius ){pos.top = -centerY + radius}
  draw();
}` Also `function down() {
  pos.top += 20;
  if(pos.top > centerY - radius ){pos.top = centerY - radius}
  draw();
}` Try to do the same for the left and right

Comment: @enxaneta thank you! this is what i was looking for~